# FFMpeg concatenation with large list of inputs -- how to minimize command line length

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a python tool that concatentates several mp4s together into a single movie file using FFMPEG run from a subprocess call. The issue is that an arbitrarily large number of inputs in the command string will hit the windows CLI character max.

`ffmpeg -y -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4 -i c.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc  -filter_complex '[0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2: (oh- ih)/2,setsar=1[0:v];[1]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(owiw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[1:v];[2]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow- iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[2:v]; [0:v][3:a][1:v][3:a][2:v][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]' -c:v libx264 -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4`

Assuming 3 input movies that may or may have audio (hence the null audio source).
This works fine assuming there are no more than 30-50 input files. Often the input files have rather long filepaths and can get long very quickly.

After doing a bit of reading I tried a simple:

`ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4`

Which works if I can guarantee that all the files are the same codec/resolution/etc, but this cannot be guaranteed.
I'm not clear on how to translate my filter_complex to work with a text file of inputs. Finding a specific enough solution has proven elusive.

I'd be perfectly fine assigning the input paths to a temporary environment variable but in my use case this doesn't seem to work either. The subprocess call doesn't seem to translate wildcard %MYVAR% calls to environment variables.

I feel like there has to be an answer to this problem. If anyone can suggest a solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not process every video individually and then concatenate them? As you said about the concat demuxer: "works if I can guarantee that all the files are the same codec/resolution/etc", if you encode them first to make them *concat-compatible* you would have solved your problem.

Comment: The idea was to keep it to a single process without having to generate extra temporary files. This would of course be a last ditch effort but if I can find a solution without having to resort to that I would prefer it.

Comment: I went ahead and ran each file as a separate transcode first and then concatenated at the end. Works fine and ended up not being a whole lot of work. Certainly a lot faster than working out some complicated transcode argument.